# Problems with 'with open', to create a trivial challenge in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like create a trivial challenge ! But it's not working as I would. This is my code :

```
import os
with open('questions','r') as file:
   l = 0
   question = []
   right_guess = []
   wrong_guess_1 = []
   wrong_guess_2 = []
   for line in file:
        content_line = []
        for char in line:
             content_line.append(char)
        if l == 0:
             question.append(content_line)
             l = 1
        elif l == 1:
             right_guess.append(content_line)
             l = 2
        elif l == 2:
             wrong_guess_1.append(content_line)
             l = 3
        elif l == 3:
             wrong_guess_2.append(content_line)
             l = 4
   if l == 4:
        break
   print(question)
   print(right_guess)
   print(wrong_guess_1)
   print(wrong_guess_2)
   input('Awnser : ')
```

Ok, now let's me explain the two problems. I've try  my code with this question file structure ( there is no extention, it's just 'question' ) :

```
 a question
      the right anwser
      false guess
      false guess
 a other question
      the right anwser
      false guess
      false guess
```

here a example, if you don't understand :

```
 How does 1 + 1 ?
  3
  0
  5
```

Obviously the answer is the second line : 3 ! ( just kidding, it's 2, I know :D )
So, let's back to our problem : I've start the code and it's give me this result :

```
 [[ 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 's', ' ', '1', '+', '1', ' ', '?', '\n']]
 [[ 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 's', ' ', '1', '+', '1', ' ', '?', '\n']]
 [[ 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 's', ' ', '1', '+', '1', ' ', '?', '\n']]
 [[ 'H', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'd', 'o', 'e', 's', ' ', '1', '+', '1', ' ', '?', '\n']]
 Answer :
```

I don't really understand where is the problem but I hope someone will help me to get this result :

```
 How does 1+1 ?
 2
 0
 5
 Answer
```

And if some of poeple who will watching this page are really crazy, I could expect have this result :

```
 (the program take one question, randomly, in the whole file)
 the chosen one
 one of the three possibles guests
 one other of the three possibles guests
 a third possible guest
 ( And we don't know which one is the correct )
 Answer :
```

I think this is all, thank to anyone who will try to give a clue, a element or who will contribute to this little program !

Comment: maybe look again at the number of equal signs in "if l = 4"

Comment: Please show actual code. There are at least three typos in this code that would prevent it from running at all; so how can we know what is causing your issue?

Comment: But also ask yourself why you are iterating through every character in a line and appending it to a list, if that isn't what you want the output to be.

Comment: @trilarion, just a error of myselft, cause I've rewrite the whole program by hand ^^

Comment: FYI, the word is "guess", not "guest". A guest is a visitor.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm gonna fix it, it hand writting of what I have on my computer, sorry for the mistakes

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've begin python since this year, so I'm not strong at all, do you have a better solution than the list ?

Comment: @Barmar Thank, it's improve my inglish, it's always helpful :D

Comment: The title is misleading; the question has nothing to do with the `with` statement used to open the file.

Comment: @chepner Do you have a better question to put for the title ? It's will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is here:

```
content_line = []
for char in line:
    content_line.append(char)
```

None of this is needed. Just use `line` for the next few lines:

```
for line in file:
    if l == 0:
        question.append(line)
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question does not give the same line multiple times as an output. If that was an issue, it is not represented in this code.

---

The reason you're getting lists instead of strings as a result is that you're explicitly *making* those lists:

```
        content_line = []
        for char in line:
             content_line.append(char)
```

If you simply used `line` directly (or `line.rstrip()` if you want to remove the newline at the end), you would get a line of text for each line in the file.

---

The reason you're getting lists *inside of lists* is that you're not only putting characters in a list, you're then appending those to another list. As it seems you only have one item per list, and that you expect a single string from printing the list, you could simply replace those lists by the strings.

Instead of appending to lists, just assign to the variables:

```
   for line in file:
        # Remove trailing whitespace at the end of the line
        content_line = line.rstrip()
        if l == 0:
             question = content_line
             l = 1
        elif l == 1:
             right_guess = content_line
             l = 2
        elif l == 2:
             wrong_guess_1 = content_line
             l = 3
        elif l == 3:
             wrong_guess_2 = content_line
             l = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this look to be the final code :

```
for line in file:
    # Remove trailing whitespace at the end of the line
    content_line = line.rstrip()
    if l == 0:
         question = content_line
         l = 1
    elif l == 1:
         right_guess = content_line
         l = 2
    elif l == 2:
         wrong_guess_1 = content_line
         l = 3
    elif l == 3:
         wrong_guess_2 = content_line
         l = 4
```

Thank you quamrana, user1018651 and anyone who ave put a comment to help me !
Anyway, It still a 'little' thing to fix and I think this is the hardest one :
Transform this code for add the random questions and get, at end, this :

```
  (the program take one question, randomly, in the whole file)
  the chosen one
  one of the three possibles guests
  one other of the three possibles guests
  a third possible guest
  ( And we don't know which one is the correct )
  Answer :
```